# Knockout issue with prototypical inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, knockout.js, prototype

I have an issue with Knockout where I prototype a user object where the observable properties of my object seem to be overwritten by the last occurrence.

Therefore I cannot use the same object more than once otherwise it will be overwritten.

Although this is hard to explain, see my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/RSEcj/1/

What am I doing wrong? (or is this a bug in Knockout?) How can I fix the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because observables are functions and not properties they are represented by a single instance on the object prototype, unlike properties which will be created on the object when they are set.

You could use functional inheritance to achieve what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/ypWQN/1/

```
var User = function(firstName, lastName){
    var that = {};

    that.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    that.lastName = lastName;

    return that;
};


var Employee = function(firstName, lastName){
    var that = User();

    that.firstName(firstName);
    that.lastName = lastName; 

    return that;
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, prototype cannot be used in conjunction with KnockOut?

Comment: Not if you want the observables to be individual to each instance. This is not KO's fault. It's just the way js works.

Comment: this method works perfectly fine, the only downside of it is that instanceof will always point to the root function.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice solution: http://jsfiddle.net/magikMaker/RSEcj/19/

It uses the new method inheritsFrom(), credits for this go to http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Combined this with the apply() method and an init() method and the magic happens... :-)

```
var Person = function(firstName, lastName){

    this.init = function(firstName, lastName){
        this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
    };

    this.setLastName = function(lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    };

    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
};

var Child = function(firstName, lastName){
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
};

Child.inheritsFrom(Person);
```

Comment: looks nice, the only problem is that you can't access the parent's constructor from the child class, e.g. to run code before the parent constructor is invoked. this is quite common practice in js

Answer (score 1):

Bit late i know, but this might help someone.

Try defining it like this, always works a treat for me

```
function User(firstName,lastName)
{
this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
this.lastName = lastName;
}

function Employee(firstName,lastName)
{
    User.apply(this,arguments);
   this.firstName(firstName);
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

Employee.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;
```