# knockout observable with inheritance

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, prototypal-inheritance

I have a problem with observables in my baseclass.
check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p2tEp/17/) fiddle to see the problem.

I will explain what i am trying to do.

I have a base class for my viewmodels that i inherit off.
This base class contains observable properties.

I i create multiple instances of my inherited classes and assign values to the observables then the value that is registered for all the instances is the value of the last assignment.

The following code explains what i mean.

```
var vm = function () {
    var test = ko.observable();
    return {
        test: test
    }
};

var subvm = function () {

};

subvm.prototype = new vm();
subvm.prototype.constructor = subvm;
subvm.prototype.parent = vm.prototype;    

var testvm1 = new subvm();
var testvm2 = new subvm();


ko.applyBindings(testvm1, $('#div1').get(0));
ko.applyBindings(testvm2, $('#div2').get(0));

testvm1.test('Value for object 1');
testvm2.test('Value for object 2');
```

​
The created viewmodels are bound to the following html :

```
<div id="div1">
    <span data-bind="text: test">test1</span>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <span data-bind="text: test">test2</span>
</div>
```

​

Am i doing something wrong of is this not supported by knockout.

I would appriciate any help on this.

Comment: Seems to work as you'd expect when correcting the jQuery selector - `div1` and `div2` aren't defined, did you mean them to be `$("#div1")` and `$("#div2")`?

Comment: Hi i just corrected it but it still does not work.
check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p2tEp/8/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout issue with prototypical inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520400/knockout-issue-with-prototypical-inheritance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inheritance model is wrong.  Both instances of `subvm` share the same instance of `test`.

Prototypical inheritance *cannot* make unique instances of lexically scoped variables seen in the parent "class" unless you ensure that the superclass constructor is actually called each time you instantiate a subclassed object.

Comment: Hi Alnitak,
My apologies but i am new to prototypical inheritance.
 
Can you give me an example of how i can ensure that the superclass constructor is called. I thought it was being called with subvm.prototype = new vm();.

Comment: I don't know how to do it right either, but I can recognise when it's done wrong.  Your current line populates the `prototype` of `subvm` with the result of _one_ call to `new vm()` and your (single) observable is created at that point.  When you subsequently call `new subvm()` it never calls `new vm()` again - all copies share the single copy of the observable that was in `vm.test`.